# Routing multiple URLs to Spring Boot Actuator's health endpoint

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have an app configured to serve Spring Boot Actuator's health endpoint at /manage/health.  Unfortunately due to some details of the infrastructure I'm deploying to I need to alias both / and /health over to /manage/health.

I don't see an option to customize just the health endpoint URL via properties.  I'm assuming there's no way to add extra @RequestMapping annotations that apply to a controller I don't own.

I'd prefer to explicitly define the required aliases as opposed to some traffic interceptor that affects the performance of all traffic.  Being relatively new to Spring, I'm unsure what the best way is to proceed and my searches aren't leading me in the right direction.

Can anyone provide some direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Configure a view controller for those URLs and either forward or redirect to the correct URL.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add a bean to the configuration to add a view controller. This been must extend `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` and simply override the `addViewControllers` method.

```
@Configuration
public class AliasWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/manage/health");
        registry.addViewController("/health").setViewName("forward:/manage/health");
    }
}
```

Or if you want to force a redirect use `addRedirectViewController` instead of `addViewController`.

```
@Configuration
public class AliasWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry. addRedirectViewController("/", "/manage/health");
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/health","/manage/health");
    }
}
```

Comment: @M. Deinum is it possible to replace url for restart? lets say with /myRestart. I want to do some actions before and then restart

Comment: as of 5.0 implementing `WebMvcConfigurer. addViewControllers` is the recommended  way.

Comment: This no longer works it seems.

Comment: Apart from fact that you should use `implements WebMvcConfigurer` instead of `extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` this should still work.